# Node.js Restify - Simple service

Tags: json, node.js, restify

I'm trying to make a server which stores Json posts, here is the server so far:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();
server.post('/message/', function create(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params)
    return next();
});

server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

I'm using the Restify client to make the posts

```
var restify = require('restify');

var client = restify.createJsonClient({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080',
  version: '*'
});

client.post('/message/', { hello: 'world' }, function(err, req, res, obj) {
  console.log('%d -> %j', res.statusCode, res.headers);
  console.log('%j', obj);
});
```

The problem is that req.params is empty. What's missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before `server.post` do `server.use(restify.bodyParser());`

Comment: I started to use Express because it has better documentation

Comment: @Federico Restify is only good if you want DTrace and even then, there are plenty of third party DTrace libs to tack on to Express... good choice in switching.